# My Filipina girlfriend's visa application to visit the US

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens

My girlfriend is in England right now and she is working there as a nurse.  She is a Filipino Citizen and has lived in the UK for almost a year now on a working visa.  She plans to visit me next year on a US visitor visa. In her visa application, is it appropriate to say that the reason for visit is to see her boyfriend?

I am a Filipino-American and I plan to petition for her to join me in the US legally. I would like her to see where I live before I start the petition in 2017.  Can anyone give me some advice/tips where to go about this.

Comment: Painting a false picture of your relationship is going to give more trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If she is honest and the nonimmigrant Visa is refused for reasons of insufficient ties to her country of residence then that sucks but it's not a disaster

If she is dishonest and they discover her dishonesty now or in the future that is likely to be a major problem for your future plans.

She should do as much as possible to show that she has a life in the UK that she does indeed intend to return to (assuming that in the short term at least that is her intention).

P.S. if you want to bring her to the US legally to live with you then I think you will need to marry her.